# numpy / pandas diff: spread the diff equally over the enclosed nan element

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array (which is not necessarily sorted):

```
[2.0, 3.0, nan, nan, nan, 5.0]
```

I want to calculate the difference on this array. The difference between the last element, 5, and the second element, 3, is 2. I want this difference of 2 to be spread over the enclosed nan elements of my numpy array.  If i try numpy.diff (I also tried using masked arrays) i get the result:

`[nan, 1, nan, nan, nan, nan]`.

where the result should look like the following:

```
[nan, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
```

UPDATE:

I got answers for the specific case above but the given answers are not valid in a more general form. for example if we have trailing/leading nan's and when we have alternately nan and values. for example:

```
[nan, nan, 2.0, 3.0, nan, nan, nan, 5.0, nan, 6.0, nan]
```

Comment: So, other than nans, is the input array sorted?  And, it looks like the idea is that the output array is also sorted.

The idea is output[i] is the average of the diff between input[i] and input[i-1], with the special case of the nans?

Comment: first question: no, the array is not necessarily sorted it could be [5, 11, 4, nan, 2] for example. second question: yes, and if input[i-1] isnan we should check input[i-2] and if input[1-2] is not nan, we spread the difference of input[i] and input[i-2] equally over input[i-1] and input[i].

Comment: What's the expected output of your update case?

Comment: My solution outputs: [ nan  nan  nan  1.   0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0. ]  on your updated test case.  Is this what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Rutger Kassies, i have been looking into pandas and they have out of the box methods to solve this general problem:

convert the array to dataframe, interpolate the dataframe and take the diff:

```
    import pandas as pd
    array = [nan, nan, 2.0, 3.0, nan, nan, nan, 5.0, nan, 6.0, nan]
    df = pd.DataFrame(array)
    interpolation = df.interpolate()
    diff = interpolation.diff()
```

the result is:

```
[NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that what you're trying to do is map the the output[i] to the difference of input[i] and input[i-1], and in the special case of nans, you want to distribute that difference across the nans, if that's the idea, I think this is what you want:

```
import numpy as np

def arrdiffs(a):
    out = np.array(np.zeros(len(a)))
    diff=np.nan
    difflen=0
    for i,e in enumerate(a):
        if i==0: 
            # in the first cell we always output nan
            out[i]=np.nan
        elif np.isnan(a[i]): 
            # when the input is nan, just increase difflen
            difflen+=1
        elif np.isnan(a[i-1]):
            # when the previous input is nan, but this one isn't
            # distribute the diff across the previous cells and this one
            difflen+=1
            m=float(abs(a[i]-diff))
            for j in range(i-difflen+1,i+1):
                out[j]=m/difflen
            difflen=0
            diff=a[i]
        else:
            # othewise simply do the diff locally between this cell and
            # previous
            out[i]=abs(a[i]-a[i-1])
            diff=a[i] # write down diff in case the next input cells are nan
            difflen=0

    return out

a=np.array([2.0,3.0,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,5.0])
print arrdiffs(a)
```

Edit: switched to 4 space tabs instead of 2, flattened the if/else into elifs,
added comments on each branch.

When I run this, I get your expected output:

```
$ python arrdiffs.py
[ nan  1.   0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5]
```

Edit: switched initial value of diff to np.nan to account for the case where we start with a series of nans, presumably we only output nan until we get to at least some initial value.  Looking to the OP for clarification on what the goal is here.  Also switched the assignment diff to a[i] in the case that a[i-1] is nan but a[i] isn't (this was a bug).  On the new test case provided by the OP:

```
[np.nan, np.nan, 2.0, 3.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5.0, np.nan, 6.0, np.nan]
```

This update code gives:

```
>>> [ nan  nan  nan  1.   0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0. ]
```

Is this what the OP wants?  Looking for clarification.

Comment: I had a bug when I first posted this which was in the loop over j.  I fixed this now.  Be sure to look at the current version, when you do the loop over j, you want to go from i-difflen+1, not i-difflen

Answer (score 1):

That should do the work:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: a = [2.0, 3.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5.0]

In [4]: s = pd.Series(a)

In [5]: result = s.reset_index()\
   ...:           .dropna()\
   ...:           .diff()\
   ...:           .pipe(lambda x: x[0]/x['index'])\
   ...:           .reindex(s.index)\
   ...:           .fillna(method='bfill')

In [6]: result[0] = np.nan

In [7]: result
Out[7]: 
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    0.5
3    0.5
4    0.5
5    0.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I don't think this is the answer he's looking for.  You see his expected output in the OP.

Comment: as I wrote you just need to assign NA to the first element. I thought this was trivial, but if you wish I'll add it to the code example

Answer (score 1):

I would simply first interpolate the nan's. This way you'll keep a nice separation between these two steps making it easier to for example change the way of interpolation.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2.0, 3.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5.0])
x = np.arange(a.size)

a_filled = np.interp(x, x[np.isfinite(a)], a[np.isfinite(a)])

np.diff(a_filled)

# results in
array([ 1. ,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5])
```

For more fancy interpolation, Pandas might be a good alternative, it also has a `.diff()` method for Dataframes.